# Laravel update user password from form with hash

Tags: database, laravel, authentication, account

So I have this form with 3 fields (User Email, Password and Password Confirm). this form posts to a route that takes me to **the following controller**:

```
public function updateUser($id, Request $request){

    //validate post data
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);

    $request->all();

    $request['email'] = $request['email'];
    $request['password'] = Hash::make($request['password']);


    $postData =  [$request['email'], $request['password']];

    User::find($id)->update($postData);

    //store status message
    Session::flash('success_msg', 'User details updated successfully!');

    return redirect()->route('admin.user');

}
```

The problem is, this code is not updating my database at all although it gives me no errors.

Basically what I am trying to do is that I want to allow the administrator to change the default account details within the admin panel. The default admin details are created by a seeder once the app is installed. (This app is single user - only the admin)

Thank you all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass key of array so that column can be identify.

```
public function updateUser($id, Request $request){
    //validate post data
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);
    $userData = $request->only(["email","password"]);
    $userData['password'] = Hash::make($userData['password']);
    User::find($id)->update($userData);
    Session::flash('success_msg', 'User details updated successfully!');
    return redirect()->route('admin.user');
}
```

Comment: I have tried this one and it works for me. now it is updating the database, however when i try to login with the new credentials, it just doesn't work. Please note that I am using the laravel Auth default login page, however, I have disabled all the other Auth routes (except logout).

Comment: share you code that how you are login ? be ensure what value you are providing here `$userData['password']`, did you cross check with another try ?

Comment: I am using just the default Laravel Login view and controllers

Comment: UPDATE: I have solved the problem. I had a function in the user controller that was double hashing the already hashed string. It works like a charm now!

Answer (score 2):

```
public function updateUser($id, Request $request){

    //validate post data
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);

    $input = $request->all();

    $input['email'] = $request['email'];
    $input['password'] = Hash::make($request['password']);

    User::find($id)->update($input);

    //store status message
    Session::flash('success_msg', 'User details updated successfully!');

    return redirect()->route('admin.user');

    }
```

Comment: what have you changed add some explanation ?

Comment: I have tried this one and it works for me. now it is updating the database, however when i try to login with the new credentials, it just doesn't work. Please note that I am using the laravel Auth default login page, however, I have disabled all the other Auth routes (except logout).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the password hashing by default in your User model by doing this

```
    public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
    }
```

than to  update user, just do this

```
User::find($id)->update($request->only('email','password'));
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution that I am searching for. It's so clever solution. Thanks

Comment: if u do, while register user you hash your pass twice, and remeber password as well hash twice